# How can I sort numbers from largest to smallest in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, list, max, min

I was able to sort the numbers in the matrix from smallest to largest, but I could not sort them from largest to smallest. please help...

```java
int[] list = new int[4];

System.out.println("Enter the numbers of array: ");
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    list[i] = kbd.nextInt();

for (int index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
    int minIndex = index;
    for (int i = index + 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] < list[minIndex])
            minIndex = i;
    }
    int temp = list[index];
    list[index] = list[minIndex];
    list[minIndex] = temp;
}

System.out.println("Numbers after sorting: ");
for (int j : list) System.out.print(j + " ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is fine.  No need to change it except below.  All you need to do is reverse the condition of the sort.  See the comment in the following code segment.

```java
for (int i = index + 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] < list[minIndex]) // change < to >
        minIndex = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] arr = new int[20];
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = random.nextInt(10);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    int[] reverseSortedArr = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .boxed()
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .mapToInt(i -> i)
            .toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverseSortedArr));
}
```

**Output:**

```
[9, 0, 8, 1, 4, 7, 3, 6, 4, 6, 7, 6, 2, 3, 8, 0, 1, 3, 5, 2]
[9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
```

```
Integer[] array = ...
Arrays.sort( array, Comparator.reverseOrder() );
```

Now the elements in the arry are sorted